# Disable front end editing only

Tags: joomla, joomla3.3

I would like to prevent users from editing article and modules in the front end. 
I know how to do it using a hack-ish way using CSS like:

```
.jsn-article-toolbar{display:none}
```

But is their any proper way to disable this functionality in the joomla administration area?

Please note that I still need the users to edit articles in the back-end.

Thanks

Comment: Do you just want the edit option not to display or do you want to prevent someone who knows how to construct an editing url to completely not be able to do that?

Comment: I would prefer the second option if possible but not to restrict him in doing edits in the backend. Just restrict him in the front end !

Comment: You could use a plugin to always redirect from that view OR do an override for that view that completely eliminates the edit fields and scripts i.e. just shows a blank page or a page with something you decide on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean "is there any proper way to disable this functionality using the joomla administration area" the answer is no (or, at least, I didn't found it).
What you can do is create an override of the com_content module in your template (if it doesn't have that already). You can create it using admin panel. Go to 
Extensions -> Template Manager -> Templates -> {yourtemplate} -> Create Overrides -> com_content -> article
then go to
Extensions -> Template Manager -> Templates -> {yourtemplate} -> Editor -> html -> com_content -> article -> default.php
find "$canEdit = $params->get('access-edit');"
and replace with "$canEdit = FALSE;"
This edit is template-dependent so you have to do it for every template you use.
You can also create a parameter for the template to control this in template options.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i will test it by monday and i ll let you know

Comment: Since edit icons don't only appear on that view (they are also in category list views and you might also consider disabling weblinks editing at the same time, so I'd actually make a system plugin that changes core.edit to a hard deny all over, in that case the layouts can't do anything.  Also the module editing in the front end has a parameter to turn it on and off  so you don't need to do anything more than that.